# Is there a way to skip over the machine calls when using breakpoints in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Question is in the title, is there a way to skip machine calls like:

```
0x294509e:  pushl  %esi
```

When stepping through Xcode code using breakpoints?

In other words, is there a way to JUST see MY code when using the stepping button when breakpoint is caught?

Comment: are those breakpoints due to possible errors?, if you manually set breakpoints it shouldnt stop at machine calls

Comment: A workaround is to set a breakpoint on the next line in your code and hit the little "play" button again.

Comment: @fzwo Yes, but I'd rather not do that for obvious reasons, thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is possible. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.